# Find the number of blocks of text in a file

Tags: perl, rotation

I have the following code

```
foreach my $filename (glob("$MY_DIR/applog_s*.log")) {

    open (FILE, $filename ) or die "can't read open $filename";

    $/ = "\n\n";

    while( <FILE> ) {
        my $count = $.;
        my @ino = stat($filename);
        push @filelist, { filename => $filename , inode => $ino[1], nrow => $count};
}
```

And the following data

```perl
"$filelist{filename};$filelist{inode};$filelist{nrow}"
```

```
applog_s0.0.log;139279;1
applog_s0.1.log;139279;2
applog_s0.2.log;139279;3
applog_s0.3.log;139279;4
applog_s1.0.log;139281;5
applog_s1.1.log;139281;6
applog_s1.2.log;139281;7
applog_s1.3.log;139281;8
applog_s2.0.log;139285;9
applog_s2.1.log;139285;10
applog_s2.2.log;139285;11
applog_s2.3.log;139285;12
applog_s3.0.log;139287;13
applog_s3.1.log;139287;14
applog_s3.2.log;139287;15
applog_s3.3.log;139287;16
```

I have two questions:

- How can I solve a bug about the counter? it doesn't restart from 1 when the file changes.
- How can I print the maximum value of my `nrow` for each filename?

**New Solution *(it works)*:**

```
foreach my $filename (glob("$MY_DIR/applog_s*.log")) {
open my $fh, '<', $filename  or die "can't read open $filename";
$/ = "\n\n";
while( <$fh> ) {
    my $inode = (stat($filename))[1];
    my @lines = split /\n\n/;

    ....
    {My data capture}
    ....

    1 while <$fh>; my $count = $.;
    push @filelist, {filename => $filename, inode => $inode, count => $count,}
    }
close ($fh);
}
```

Comment: Check your loop structure: you're initialising `$count` and `stat`-ing the file while you're supposed to be reading the file. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: This is quite strange code. Is your filename in `$filename` or `$INFILE`? Why have the outer `while` loop when you have that inner loop that will read every record from the filehandle? And I thought I explained that you don't need to explicitly close filehandles that are held in a lexical variable.

Comment: i'm sorry IN_FILE it's an error

Comment: You say it's `$IN_FILE`, but you've now corrected it to `$filename` everywhere. You're not the most detail-oriented programmer I've ever dealt with :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you read the documentation for `$.` in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), you'll see that it says:

> `$.` is reset when the filehandle is closed, but not when an open filehandle is reopened without an intervening `close()`.

And that's what you're falling over here. You constantly re-open `FILE` without closing it first - so `$.` just carries on getting larger.

You could add a call to `close()` at the end of your loop. But I think it's a better idea to switch to using lexical filehandles instead - so they get closed automatically at the end of each iteration of the loop.

```
foreach my $filename (glob(...)) {
  open my $fh, '<', $filename or die ...;

  local $/ = "\n\n"; # Always localise changes to $/!

  while (<$fh>) {
    ...
  }
}
```

As for your other question, I think you need some rather more drastic refactoring of your code. You seem to be adding a value to `@filelist` for every line in every file - and it sounds like you really only want one value in `@filelist` for each file.

Something like this:

```
foreach my $filename (glob(...)) {
  open my $fh, '<', $filename or die ...;

  local $/ = "\n\n"; # Always localise changes to $/!

  my @data = <$fh>; # You don't seem to use this data anywhere
  my $inode = (stat($filename))[1];
  push @filelist, {
    filename => $filename,
    inode    => $inode,
    count    => $.,
  }
}
```

Comment: In your opinion, there is a way to take directly last row of my opened file ?

Comment: This is a FAQ. [How do I count the number of lines in file?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file%3f)

Comment: @AllanSimeoe try to make an if before of push, if <last row of file> = $. then: push

Comment: @DaveCross your help was usefully, i've write the following code and it works better   my $count = `/usr/bin/wc -l $filename`;
  my $count = (split /\s/, $count)[0];
  push @filelist, {filename => $IN_FILE, inode => $inode, count => $count,}
 }
close ($fh);
}
@$filelist = do {my %seen;
   grep { !$seen{ $_->{ filename }, $_->{ inode }, $_->{ count } }++ } @$filelist};

Comment: @AllanSimeoe: Please don't put code in comments - it's unreadable there. If you want to show us what you ended up with, then edit your question to add it there.

Comment: @Allan: Please don't change the code in your question: it makes nonsense of the answers and comments posted so far. You can *add to* your question to provide additional information. I've rolled back your most recent edit.

Comment: @AllanSimeoe: Please note that I suggested you should **add** the solution to your question. Removing the original code is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Allan: Shelling out to a new process just to use `wc` is slow and wasteful. Much better to do it in Perl with `1 while <$fh>; my $count = $.`.  Also, if you're counting *blocks of text* separated by blank lines then you should set `$/` to the empty string `$/ = ""`. This will do what you want but will allow for any number of blank lines between the blocks.

Comment: @Borodin thank you for your suggestion, i try to made this change right now :)

Comment: You should always close files since it's the last chance to report any error. `close FILE or die "could not close FILE: $!\n";`

Comment: @shawn: There is rarely any point in closing input files, and using lexical file handles with proper scoping makes an explicit close unnecessary unless you need to test the return status.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, exactly. Test the return status to see if an error occurred during a read.

Comment: @shawnhcorey ok, as suggested, I will add it

Comment: @DaveCross You're missing the point, that being to test for errors.

Comment: @Borodin I noticed that using 1 while <$fh>; my $count = $. the number of lines is correctly reported, however, I leave the previously activated while loop earlier.

Comment: @Allan: You don't need two `while` loops!

Comment: @Borodin but if i write my $count = $.; it write more and more row (1,2,..,n) ...

Comment: @Allan: Seriously, if you can't program at all then you have come to the wrong place. Questions are assumed to have come from people who stood a good chance of solving the problem themselves but have hit a road block. If you don't even know what the code you've written means then you need to do some serious studying. The Stack Overflow [tag information page for Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) has many useful links. What you're currently doing ridicules the programming profession, as anyone can write anything by posting a requirement here and waiting for the answer.

Comment: @Allan: Please don't use real people on line to learn a programming language. Most of us have better things to do. Think of it as being unable to drive your car. If you have checked the battery, distributor, coil, and spark plugs and they're okay *then* you can ask. If someone asks what happens if you press the accelerator and you answer *"which is the accelerator"* then you're asking the wrong people. Learn to drive.